# Permanently save pictures in collection view

Tags: ios, database, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview

I'm building an app where you have the option to create a photo album. When you do so, you will be brought to a collection view where you can add photos from the library. When the users closes the app, i want the pictures to be permanently saved into the collection view. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can use `CoreData` for that.

Comment: Please, read something about MVC software architectural pattern. @NiravDoctorwala, CoreData not the best place for saving pictures

Answer (score 1):

1) Create one plist file which is of type mutable array.

2) It will store dictionary with keys like image name, imagepath etc...

3) Store images inside application directory with folder structure.

Create a PhotoAlbum directory inside application document directory and store it inside the directory.

You can save image by `datetime.png(systemdate)`. So it will be unique all time.

Every time when you open the app, you have to access the plist file which gives you the number of images which you have stored.